# myBatis Callable Statement - java Date Issue

Tags: mybatis, java.util.date, callable-statement

I was using mybatis-3.1.1 and there was no issue in the following code.

DAO Implementation

```
    @Override
public ItunesPriorityReportDates getWeeklyPriorityDates(Date reportRunDate){

    ItunesPriorityReportDates itunesPriorityReportDates = new ItunesPriorityReportDates();
    Map<String,Object> weeklyPriorityDatesParamMap = new HashMap<>();

    weeklyPriorityDatesParamMap.put("reportRunDate", reportRunDate);

    log.debug("Report Run Date : " + reportRunDate);

    this.getItunesAnalysisMapper().getWeeklyPriorityDates(weeklyPriorityDatesParamMap);

    itunesPriorityReportDates.setAriaWeekStartDate((Date)weeklyPriorityDatesParamMap.get("ariaWeekStartDate"));
    itunesPriorityReportDates.setAriaWeekEndDate((Date)weeklyPriorityDatesParamMap.get("ariaWeekEndDate"));
    itunesPriorityReportDates.setitunesAccountPeriodStartDate((Date)weeklyPriorityDatesParamMap.get("itunesAccountPeriodStartDate"));
    itunesPriorityReportDates.setitunesAccountPeriodEndDate((Date)weeklyPriorityDatesParamMap.get("itunesAccountPeriodEndDate"));

    return itunesPriorityReportDates;

}
```

Mapper

```
    public ItunesPriorityReportDates getWeeklyPriorityDates(Map<String,Object> weeklyPriorityDatesParamMap);
```

Mapper XML.

```
    <select id="getWeeklyPriorityDates" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" statementType="CALLABLE">
    {CALL external_reporting.itunes_sales.get_weekly_priority_dates(#{reportRunDate                 mode=IN, jdbcType=DATE},
                                                                    #{ariaWeekStartDate             mode=OUT, jdbcType=DATE},
                                                                    #{ariaWeekEndDate               mode=OUT, jdbcType=DATE},
                                                                    #{itunesAccountPeriodStartDate  mode=OUT, jdbcType=DATE},
                                                                    #{itunesAccountPeriodEndDate    mode=OUT, jdbcType=DATE}
                                                                    )
    }
</select>
```

After upgrading to mybatis-3.2.5 now it is passing null as DATE to Oracle procedure.

Can you please help me with this? Not sure whether I have to update my mapper XML and include something to tell it to parse correctly.

I am using java.util.Date in java.

Thanks
Chirag

Comment: Have you tried jdbcType=TIMESTAMP?  That's what I use.

Comment: Tried. myBatis developer helped me and they solved this. This was undocumented change which happened about year back.  They stopped using space as a separator. I didn't had comma between property name and the MODE.  #{reportRunDate                 mode=IN,   just added comma after reportRunDate and worked like a charm.  Same thing add comma after each property name and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution from Eduardo Macarron (myBatis developer)

I got it. It is an interesting finding. Have a look at the expression you posted.

## {reportRunDate mode=IN, jdbcType=DATE},

There is no comma separating the property name and the mode!

What is happening is that 3.0 and 3.1 admitted using an space as a separator, though that was undocumented, untested and at least in my case unknown :)

3.2 parsing code was improved and now it supports a well defined grammar:

- Inline parameter expression parser. Supported grammar (simplified):
- - 
- inline-parameter = (propertyName | expression) oldJdbcType attributes
- propertyName = /expression language's property navigation path/
- expression = '(' /expression language's expression/ ')'
- oldJdbcType = ':' /any valid jdbc type/
- attributes = (',' attribute)*
- attribute = name '=' value
- 

And the space is not a valid separator (so properties can in fact be called "input date").

This change was unwanted but was introduced in 3.2 one year ago so I am afraid we  cannot go back.

I hope you just missed the comma and that was not intentional. Sorry!